# How to implement MDTabBar with swipe to move tab in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, material-design

How to implement **MDTabBar** with swipe to move tab and change view controller like android.

I checked **CarbonKit** it works perfect for me, but I need to implement MDTabBar.

**CarbonKit** : https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

**MDTabBar** : https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/Tabs

**Other links** : [Material Design for iOS](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an example project in the git repository.

Comment: Yes, but error while i install pod, so can't start sample project.

Comment: You have to install the complete examples project via pod. Don't install individual project.

Comment: I have downloaded source code from this link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-ios-swift/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 and not any tab bar like android.

Comment: You can bring the same effect with Container view embedded with collection view controller. Do you want the sample code to implement it ?

Comment: http://www.conradomateu.com/swift%20tutorials/Tab-Bar-Switcher/   The link explains how to switch between tabbar by swiping left and right